# Not able to install .ipa via iTunes after updating to iOS 9.3.1

Tags: macos, ios, itunes, ipad, xcode

I used to create the ipa file from Xcode/Product/Archive and install it via iTunes. After updating the iPad to iOS 9.3.1, the app keeps showing "Installing" in iTunes and disappears the installing icon on iPad after loading but never completed.
With the Build and run the current scheme option, this app can install on iPad.

I had already updated my Xcode to 7.3 and iTunes. Any solutions to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: i didn't find any solution yet. i am also facing the same issue exactly what you are facing?

Comment: Have you tried posting this to StackOverflow instead of Ask Different?  You might find people more knowledgeable about Xcode on that site.

Comment: I had already posted. Both didn't replied.

Comment: Have you tried Cydia impactor?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I know we need the enterprise account for in house distributions.

Alternate solutions are using

1. Using third party's solution, I used https://www.diawi.com/. It works perfect.
2. Using your apple developer account, add your devices' UDID number and used development team profile to install. Only 100 devices are allowed.
   Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Click the project on the lefts side.. General->deployment info  change deployment target to 9.3 version...and archive the project and take ipa file once more and add ipa file to itune. hope this helps.thankz

[image]

Comment: I had already tried on this option. I am not able to export the installable ipa. Set the active scheme to Generic iOS Device. thanks.

Comment: @Zarli hey try one more method.. open xcode-> windows->devices select device. after that install ipa file through that.... Hope this helps for you

Comment: this option is for the specific device. I need it for all compatible devices. Thanks.